# Back UPS, programmatically get remaining power

Tags: command-line, ups

I just bought a [Back-UPS](https://www.apc.com/shop/mk/en/products/APC-Back-UPS-750VA-Tower-230V-4x-IEC-C13-AVR/P-BX750MI).

So that if there is a power outage, this serves as some sort of a backup power.

I have set it up. It works, even when I plug it out.

But what I want to happen, is that the computer connected to it, will run maybe a cron job every ten minutes, to see how much battery is remaining, and if its below, say, 30%.
Then it implements a proper shutdown.

But I can't seem to find, how to determine programmatically, how much power is left on the ups.

Does anybody know how to get that information?

Comment: idk that one specifically, but they normally can tell the computer  over USB to shut down gracefully when they're running out of power.

Comment: Why bother rolling your own? Use [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.org/) instead.

Comment: I was just going to suggest http://www.apcupsd.org/ as well. I used it for several years on a server that didn't support APC's client software and it worked very well. And you get the source code, if it doesn't quite meet your needs.

Comment: I have a similar unit in the basement. After 10 minutes, you need to shut down all computers (or the UPS may do that for you). 10 -15 minutes is all you get for non-battery powered computers. After that, laptops and network (modem, router) should go longer.

Comment: why bother? this apcupsd seems to be a huge bother. and nut is crazy difficult to setup as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the upc is just plugged to the computer via electric plugin

You'll need to *additionally* plug it in to the computer via USB. There's a USB port somewhere on the UPS – hopefully standard Type-B these days, though APC has been known to use weird RJ45-ish (10P10C?) connectors for USB. Some other UPS types use a RS232 serial port.

Once the UPS shows up in `lsusb` (likely as some kind of serial or HID device), install some software that can talk to it. For APC specifically, `apcupsd` seems to be common; APC is also one of the many UPS types supported by `nut` (Network UPS Tools).

I've only ever used the latter software, but it has the `upsc` command to interrogate the UPS-monitor daemon about battery state (and many more parameters); I assume apcupsd has something similar, as that's kind of the whole point.

Most likely you won't even need a cronjob – the UPS monitoring software almost always has preemptive shutdown built-in.

Comment: im trying to install nut, going by directions here https://zackreed.me/installing-nut-on-ubuntu/. the second command to change, /etc/nut/ups.conf. gives me permission error. i could sudo, but that creates problems later. do you know how i should proceed with this?

Comment: @john-jones - Sounds like a question that has an answer that can’t fit in a comment

Comment: sudo creates problems **if you sudo the wrong things**. There's a time when you need to use sudo and there's a time when you don't. If you need to edit a file that is in /etc and is owned by root, then you need root privileges, whether you obtain them via sudo or otherwise.

Comment: yes and i don't have any choice for the document tells me to edit a file, which i don't have permission to edit without sudo.

Comment: Then edit it with sudo?

Comment: thats what i did, and then later there is an error and i dont know if its because i edited it with sudo or not. im totally stuck on that catalogue it doesn't really work when i implement it. and im totally stuck.

Comment: no wait, i am able to get it doing what it needs. its just an extremely confusing and poorly written manual. its more like a first draft. that's never been updated, for some reason.

Comment: but its apparently the best there is.